# Error when I try to pass variable to apollo (GraphQl) mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I use apollo mutation in my react app. Everything worked until I try to pass a variable to this mutation. My code:

```
const DELETE_WORD = gql`
  mutation($eng_word: String!) {
    deleteWord(eng_word: $engWord) {
      eng_word
    }
  }
`;
const deleteWord = engWord => {
  deleteWordHook({ variables: { engWord } }).then(closeModal());
  refetch();
};
```

After calling deleteWord I receive error which doesn't provide any valuable feedback.

It is working code (without passing variable):

```
const DELETE_WORD = gql`
    mutation {
      deleteWord(eng_word: "apple") {
        eng_word
      }
    }
  `;
const deleteWord = engWord => {
    deleteWordHook().then(closeModal());
    refetch();
  };
```

Comment: $eng_word vs $engWord - use 2nd one in both places

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong param to your mutation. You should pass `eng_word` to variables of deleteWordHook. 
Try this:

```js
const DELETE_WORD = gql`
  mutation($eng_word: String!) {
    deleteWord(eng_word: $engWord) {
      eng_word
    }
  }
`;
const deleteWord = engWord => {
  deleteWordHook({ variables: { eng_word: engWord } }).then(closeModal());
  refetch();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

since your are passing **engWord** as varaible at the point of invocation of mutation,
you should use the same name while declaring the mutation too. Changing your code like below should work

```
const DELETE_WORD = gql`
      mutation($engWord: String!) {
        deleteWord(eng_word: $engWord) {
```